# What can you do in CoreBluetooth background delegate calls?

Tags: core-bluetooth

I am using Core Bluetooth in my project. I have included Session Backgrounding to avail its background mode functionality. I have observed that the delegate for peripheral disconnection,

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error;
```

gets called in the background mode. However any code I write in this method is not executed except for NSLogs. Can somebody explain exactly what kind of code can be executed here?

My aim is to send this disconnection notification to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems it was some issue at my end. According the the documentation your app is woken (in the background) for around 10 seconds when it gets a bluetooth related delegate call.

You can use this time to perform any non view updating task and even request for additional time using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

My code looks like this.

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    [self sendEmailInBackground:peripheral]; //Code to send a server request
    return;
}
```

and its working in the background mode. This also works when the phone is in lock state.